# how to merge two column values as option values for dropdown using Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables for example

table_A, table_B

```
table_A
id username
5  kumar
6  pavan

table_B
id userid rname
1         testing
2    5    --
3         newtest
4    6    --
```

what i want is

```
<select>
  <option value='1'>testing</option>
  <option value='2'>kumar</option>
  <option value='3'>newtest</option>
  <option value='4'>pavan</option>
</select>
```

if rname is empty means (--) so based on userid from table_B, get username from table_A, so how do we display using laravel query with pluck

Comment: Try: `$first = ModelName::where('<fieldName>','<searchText>')
        ->get();  $second = Modelname::where('<fieldName>','<searchText>')
    ->get();

$finalResult = $first->merge($second);  $finalResult->each(function($record)
{
    echo $record-><fieldName>.'<br />';
});`

Answer (score 1):

Use Laravel `belongsTo()` relationship. Make two model as `TableA` and `TableB`. In `TableB` model, make a relationship to `TableA` like-

```
public function tableA()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TableA::class,'userid');
}
```

And then in your controller-

```
$tableb_datas = TableB::with('tableA')->get();

return view('your_view')->with('tableb_datas', $tableb_datas);
```

And last in your view-

```
<select>
    @foreach($tableb_datas as $b)
          @if($b->rname!="--")
             <option value='{{$b->id}}'>{{$b->rname}}</option>
          @else
             <option value='{{$b->id}}'>{{$b->tableA->username}}</option>
          @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) function.  The `merge()` method merges the given array or collection with the original collection.

```
$first = table_A::all();
$second = table_B::all();

$finalResult = $first->merge($second);
$result = $finalResult->all();


$finalResult->each(function($record) {
    echo $record-><fieldName>.'<br />';
});
```

Hope this helps you!